# ¿Cómo desactivar la webcam por defecto con jitsi meet en javascript?

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando desactivar la camara web en jitsi meet ya que cuando se carga la pagina donde se muestra la reunion de jitsi automaticamente la camara está encendida, lo que deseo es que la camara no se active al cargar la pagina
este es mi codigo:

```js
function meetjit(){
 
   
    const domain = 'meet.jit.si';
const options = {
   
    roomName: "dasssd",
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet')
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
}

}
window.onload = meetjit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-iframe), puedes incluir opciones para sobreescribir algunos valores por defecto. Para tu caso específico, sería algo como:

```
...
const options = {
   
    roomName: "dasssd",
    width: 1000,
    height: 500,
    configOverwrite: { startWithVideoMuted: true },
    parentNode: document.querySelector('#meet')
};
const api = new JitsiMeetExternalAPI(domain, options);
...
```

Los valores a modificar en el configOverwrite están definidos en [este archivo](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/config.js) de jitsi.

¿Ya te recomendé comenzar siempre por leer la documentación oficial? Bueno, pues te recomiendo comenzar siempre por la documentación oficial. Son otros programadores tratando de hacernos saber cómo hicieron las cosas, no los ignores ;)